# Troubleshooting Pandoc's LaTeX output: longtable alignment and line break issues

Tags: longtable, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert a `markdown` document to `tex`.

The document includes a table, for which the source code is:

```
| Video       | Pose Estimation | Notation | Gloss     | English Translation         |
| :----------: | :-----------: | :-------: | :-----------: | :----------------: |
| ![ASL HOUSE](assets/videos/original/asl_house.gif){ width=2.5cm }           | ![ASL HOUSE](assets/videos/pose/asl_house.gif){ width=2.5cm }           | ![HOUSE](assets/writing/house.png){ width=1cm }             | HOUSE             | House                                |
| ![ASL WRONG-WHAT](assets/videos/original/asl_wrong_what.gif){ width=2.5cm } | ![ASL WRONG-WHAT](assets/videos/pose/asl_wrong_what.gif){ width=2.5cm } | ![WRONG-WHAT](assets/writing/wrong_what.png){ width=0.7cm } | WRONG-WHAT        | What's the matter?<br> What's wrong? |
| ![ASL DIFFERENT](assets/videos/original/asl_different.gif){ width=2.5cm }   | ![ASL DIFFERENT](assets/videos/pose/asl_different.gif){ width=2.5cm }   | ![DIFFERENT](assets/writing/different.png){ width=1cm }     | DIFFERENT<br> BUT | Different<br> But                    |
```

If I generate the table in HTML, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I generate it with pdflatex, it looks like:
Notice the "Gloss" and "English Translation" are

1. Aligned to the bottom
2. Don't break line between "Different" and "But"

[image]

What is wrong with the LaTeX it is generating?

```tex
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.1846}}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.2000}}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.1385}}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.2000}}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 8\tabcolsep) * \real{0.2769}}@{}}
\toprule\noalign{}
\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\centering
Video
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\centering
Pose Estimation
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\centering
Notation
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\centering
Gloss
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}\centering
English Translation
\end{minipage} \\
\midrule\noalign{}
\endhead
\bottomrule\noalign{}
\endlastfoot
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/original/asl_house.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/pose/asl_house.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{parts/background/assets/writing/house.png}
& HOUSE & House \\
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/original/asl_wrong_what.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/pose/asl_wrong_what.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=0.7cm]{parts/background/assets/writing/wrong_what.png}
& WRONG-WHAT & What's the matter? What's wrong? \\
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/original/asl_different.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{parts/background/assets/videos/pose/asl_different.png}
&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{parts/background/assets/writing/different.png}
& DIFFERENT BUT & Different But \\
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You could try https://github.com/pandocker/pandocker-lua-filters/blob/master/lua/table-width.lua

Comment: At first glance is only that "Pose estimation" is too big to fit it only in a single line, thus forcing a blank line in the other headers. At the contrary, "Different But" have enough space, so there are no reason for a  line break (`<br>` is not latex nor markdown syntax, so it is used in HTML format but  miserably **ignored** in the latex export).